# JBoss 4.2.3 - UserTransaction not bound, not published

Tags: jboss, jndi

I'm running JBoss 4.2.3. When I look at the JNDIView, I do not see UserTransaction in the Global JNDI Namespace.

This is causing the following error in my webapp:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction not bound
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
```

This problem is happening on my remote hosting service (eapps). However, on my local machine, which is also running 4.2.3, it's fine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Some months ago, I had tried to get RMI over HTTP to work. Got it half working and then got distracted and forgot about it. I just copied over some original versions of the files that I had edited, and it all worked again.